# Unable to access bookinfo productpage Istio using external IP and custom domain

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, istio, svc, istio-gateway

I have deployed Istio controlplane service on Openshift cluster, Deployed the book info application.
Assigned external Ip to ingress service:
oc -n testbed get svc

```
istio-egressgateway         LoadBalancer   172.21.193.228   2471b4f9-us-east.lb.appdomain.cloud,10.40.1.8   80:31894/TCP,443:30662/TCP,15443:32043/TCP                   37h
istio-ingressgateway        LoadBalancer   172.21.240.99    9fa76ab7-us-east.lb.appdomain.cloud,10.40.1.9   15021:32453/TCP,80:30380/TCP,443:30519/TCP,15443:32361/TCP   37h
```

I deployed gateway as below :

```
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  labels:
    release: istio
  name: custom-ingressgateway
  namespace: testbed
  resourceVersion: "36057065"
  uid: f85e8a19-d433-4a42-ba37-9b5401b395e3
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "ingress.qa.ipccpaas.com"
    - "10.40.1.9"
    - "*"
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
```

Deployed the virtual service as below :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "10.40.1.9"
  gateways:
  - custom-ingressgateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

The hosts in gateway and virtual service are matched , below is the route created for external ip :

```
oc -n testbed get routes 
testbed-custom-ingressgateway-a9879f6b7f9bb51e   10.40.1.9                                                                                                                                                       istio-ingressgateway   http2                        None
```

When I try to hit http://10.40.1.9/productpage from browser , its timing out. However if I ssh to any workernode and curl the http://10.40.1.9/productpage , it is working.

If I mention "hosts" as "*" in both gateway and virtual service and try to access with cloud provided LB endpoint , Im able too access applicatin from browser.

We are using VPN foor cloud, Do you thinks its VPC firewall issue or any wrong configuration on above istio ?

Comment: Which version of Istio did you use?

Comment: Istio Operator 2.1 Installed.

Comment: So please provide reproduction steps. Please describe how did you exactly set up your environment.

Comment: On one occurrence you've used the exact internal IP and in another you've used the LB endpoint, couldn't the issue stem from this?